# Bound for the truncation error

Tags: numerical-methods, truncation-error

I am trying to find the minimal bound for the truncation error of the following problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNMmc.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by "minimal bound'? The lowest possible upper bound? That would be the actual difference between the two functions, which they said is not known. Do not expect us to come up with a solution for that!

Comment: No, I’m looking for the lower bound of the truncation error, the upper one is given to us already.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the" lower bound. There are plenty of lower and upper bounds. Since the terms are all positive, one lower bound is just $0$. Further, because $S_0(a,b)$ converges, $0$ is the best possible constant lower bound. Any higher number will eventually be greater than $S_2(k,a,b)$. If you want something different, you will need to be more specific.

Comment: No sir, it is actually impossible that the lower bound for the truncation error of S an infinite sum through a finite sum is zero. What you just said makes no sense. You are not understanding what truncation means I guess. Truncation means shortening , which mathematically refers to replacing an infinite process by a finite one. For this reason, we can say that the infinite sum So(with a=A and b = B) is equal to S1( K,A,B) + S2(K,A,B) where S2 consists on the truncation error of S1 for the specific values of K,A and B (k is the number of summands counted from left to right from the sum S0)

Comment: One of us is not making sense, but you are wrong about which. Of course I understand what truncation error is! But you apparently are having real trouble with the concept of "lower bound". For every $k, S_2(k,a,b) \ge 0$. This is something that is trivial to show: $$S_2(k,a,b) = \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac 1{(an+b)(an+b+1)}$$as all the terms in this sum are positive, it is impossible for that sum to ever be less than $0$. And that is the *definition* of $0$ being a lower bound for the truncation error.

Comment: You are not understanding the problem then…

Comment: You have to find a lower bound for the remainder or error, which is S2

Comment: It is impossible for S2 to be zero

Comment: No, you are not understanding the meaning of the words "lower bound". GO LOOK IT UP, if you cannot bring yourself to believe me. A lower bound for a set $S$ is a number $a$ such that for all $s\in S, a \le s$. There is no requirement that any $s \in S$ actually equal $a$ (and sequences are sets). Even a greatest lower bound does not have to be a member of the set. For instance, the greatest lower bound of $\left\{\frac 1n  :  n\in \Bbb N_+\right\}$ is $0$, even though $0$ is not in the set. Any number higher than $0$ is also higher than some members of the set and so is not a lower bound.

Comment: And this is it for me. I'm tired of trying to talk some sense in you while you just ignore what I am saying and throwing out trash arguments that merely demonstrate that you do not even know what the words you are using even mean. If want to be wrong, it is on your head. But you'll not find any other help, as you've made it clear that you are unteachable.

Comment: Totally right man, sorry. Im just a student willing to learn, and sometimes it’s hard to accept things that are opposite to what is thought to be right since they sound really silly when you misunderstand something. Also, I wanted to leverage this and ask you why when talking about errors, like on this case an error from a truncation, we only focus on the upper bound and not on the lower bounds as well, so that then we can bound the error both with a lower and upper bound, so that we can say the exact result will be the approximated one plus some error inside the bounded set found

Comment: Because the smaller error is, the better. What we are concerned about is making sure our error is not too large. There is no such thing as too small. We are not trying to miss the target. When we can come up with easily calculated lower bounding sequences on the error (such as might be possible here), then we generally subtract off that sequence, and view the result as an improved algorithm for calculating the value, not as a lower bound on the error. But when the terms of the summation are not all positive, this is usually impossible.